# What happened when assigning an rvalue reference to lvalue?

Tags: c++, move, rvalue

I have a simple example:

```
void Message::move_Folders(Message *m) {
    m_folders = std::move(m->m_folders);
    for (auto f : m_folders) {
        f->removeMessage(m);
        f->addMessage(this);
    }
    m->m_folders.clear();
}
```

This function can move the "folders" member from one to another. So I want to know: Need I provide a move assign function for "folders"?

```
folders &operator=(folders &&f) {
    ...
}
```

What happened when assigning an rvalue reference to lvalue? Is it still a copy operation? (I believe not.)

Note: folders is a set of the Folder objects. A message may belong to many folders. So a message contains a set of Folders. The Folder also has a member `messages`. A folder may contain many messages. It's a little complicated.

This is the definition of `Message` and `Folder`:

```
class Message {
public:
// constructor and destructor
...
private:
    std::set<Folder *> m_folders;
...
};

class Folder {
friend class Message;
//constructor and destructor
...
private:
    std::set<Message *> m_messages;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: in your example `folders` is a member variable and a type, thats rather confusing

Comment: folders is a set of the Folder objects. A message may belong to many folders. So a message contains a set of Folders.

Comment: @ZhenYang please include the definition of `folders` in the question, I think not havng it is causing confusion.  Please read [mcve]

Comment: @RichardCritten I have added the definition of Message and Folder. I think the std::set has performed the move-assignment. Do you think so? But the m->m_folders.clear(); is unnecessary as xtofl said.

Comment: `folders &operator=(folders &&f)` should probably be `Folder& operator=(Folder&& f)` , thats what initially caused my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `std::move` does not move a thing; rather it makes the thing *movable*.  So in order to actually move the `m->folders` into `this->folders`, indeed the move assignment must perform that logic.

In fact, that move assignment should be the one responsible to define the move semantics: the `move_folders` method does not have to clear `m->folders` since it should not know this detail.

Comment: I missed something. The 'folders' is a set of 'Folder'. It's an std::set. So the expression: 'folders = std::move(m->folders);' will call the std::set move-assignment to move. I don't need to do anything. Right?

Comment: That's right.  Actually _I_ missed that fact.  My guess is that the set move assignment _does_ a clear of the incoming argument.  I'm not sure that's guaranteed, though.  On the other hand, it should not matter.

Comment: Note that after move std::set is in an unspecified valid state, where you can call methods on it without any preconditions, but if you are want to continue using it e.g. inserting items in it, then you need to call clear to set it to a specified state.

Comment: Note that even though `folders` currently is an `std::set`, the "express ideas directly in code" guideline hints that you should create a class for it (which may use a `set` for convenience).  Cf. http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-direct

Answer (score 2):

The need to provide a user defined move assignment depends on what other special members you have already defined, see the image for combinations:
[image]

So if Folders does not have a user defined destructor, copy constructor or assignment operator, then move constructor and assignment will be implicitly declared by the compiler. Otherwise you will need to write one yourself.

> What happened when assigning an rvalue to lvalue? Is it still a copy operation? (I believe not.)

It depends if you have a move assignment it will move, else it will copy.

Finally do you need move assignment for your Folder class to move std::set is actually No, since the move assignment of std::set does not move the contents one by one with the default allocator.

Comment: Yes, I get it. But the picture is a bit complicated. I need time to understand it.

Comment: Credit where credit is due.  Where does the picture come from?

Comment: Howard Hinnant's presentation "Everything You Ever Wanted To Know About Move Semantics (and then some)" from ACCU 2014 conference

Answer (score 0):

You do not *need* to provide a move-assignment operator, but if you don't the call will indeed be downgraded to a copy.

Comment: Yes. If the folders is not an std::set, it will be a copy.